# Include dynamic value in column name

Tags: dynamic

I have this little table:

```
cases <- c("1182025")
deceased <- c("7639")
TI_7  <- c(1100.3)

df <- data.frame(cases, deceased, TI_7)
```

and a dynamic value (year_kw_vorW).

```
currentTime <- format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d")
currentTime <- as.Date(currentTime, "%Y-%m-%d")
year <- format(Sys.time(), "%Y")
vorwoche <- currentTime - 7
kw_vorW <- lubridate::isoweek(vorwoche)
year_kw_vorW <- paste0(year,"-",kw_vorW)
```

Now I would like to include this value (year_kw_vorW) into the column name (which is not working).

```
names(df) <- c("Cases", "Deceased", "Incidence `r year_kw_vorW`")
```

[image]

I am very grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

paste worked perfectly

```
names(df) <- c("Cases", "Deceased", paste0("Incidence ", year_kw_vorW))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).